# Escape single quote in a json string already containing single quote

Tags: javascript, parsing, escaping

I have json which is stored in db as string, like below

```
Json String : "{ '1': 'This is text's 1', '2': 'This is text's 2', '3': 'This : is text's 3' }"
```

Now while parsing its giving error as its not in proper format, which should look like

```
Json String : "{ '1': 'This is text\'s 1', '2': 'This is text\'s 2', '3': 'This : is text\'s 3' }"
```

so that it can be easily parsed.

So the problem is, this format can't be changed now and gives error while parsing :( 
If i do replace the ' with replace method it replaces all ', like this

```
Json String : "{ \'1\': \'This is text\'s 1\', \'2\': \'This is text\'s 2\', \'3\': \'This : is text\'s 3\' }"
```

Is there any way i can parse them or first escape ' in the text to \' not rest of ' outside the sentence, then parse that.

Comment: I thought JSON keys and string values need to be surrounded with double quotes, not single

Comment: That isn't JSON; JSON requires double-quotes and correct escaping.  You should use a real JSON serializer.

Comment: Yes that's right, but i hope on the server API, they have created such structure manually, which totally surprised me.

Comment: Anyhow, i hope it need to be handled on the server API, they need to change the format as well as need to escape them. No other way round :(